# Aplicar una condicional a una serie de rangos en r

Tags: r

Querida comunidad solicito de su amable colaboración con la siguiente cuestión:

tengo una base de datos en donde na columna tiene valores numéricos algunos dados en millones, otos en miles por ejemplo:

```
MONTO
4
2000
5000000
15
1600000
164000000
```

A estos valores les requiero aplicar unas condicionales para tratar de unificar la información de modo que:

- los valores inferiores a 1000 sean multiplicados por 1000000
- los valores > a 1000 < 100000, multiplicarlos por 1000
- los valores > a 100000 < 1000000, multiplicarlos por 100
- y los valores superiores a 1000000 dejarlos tal cual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes anidar las condiciones usando `ifelse()`:

```
MONTO <- c(4, 2000, 5000000, 15, 1600000, 164000000)

prod <- ifelse(MONTO < 1000, 1000000, 
          ifelse(MONTO < 100000, 1000,
               ifelse(MONTO < 1000000, 100, 1)))

MONTO * prod
```

Otra forma algo más rara es usar `cut()` para generar un factor por cada rango y luego quedarnos con el valor a multiplicar:

```
prod <- as.numeric(as.character(cut(MONTO, c(-Inf, 1000, 100000, 1000000, Inf), labels = c(1000000, 1000, 100, 1))))
MONTO * prod
```

O con `tidyverse`, puedes usar `case_when()`

```
library("tidyverse")

prod <- case_when(
          MONTO < 1000 ~ 1000000,
          MONTO < 100000 ~ 1000,
          MONTO < 1000000 ~ 100,
          TRUE ~ 1
)
MONTO * prod
```

Comment: Patricio, me funciono de maravillas, una vez mas Mil gracias.