# Cómo crear un vector categórico?

Tags: r, rstudio, dataset

estoy realizando un ejercicio en RStudio, en el que me pide realizar la siguiente tarea:

**"Crea un vector categórico llamado "categoría" en función de que si la puntuación de las reseñas tiene de 0 a 49 sea "No Aconsejable", de 50 a 75, "Estandar" y de 76 a 100 "Top"**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad me he bloqueado y no soy capaz ni de saber por donde empezar. Os agradecería mucho vuestra ayuda. Cuento con los paquetes Dplyr y Tidyr.

No puse nada porque estoy bloqueada y no se por donde empezar, realicé lo siguiente pero no sé como crear la columna categoría en el dataframe, probé a poner `**categoria <- factor(c("No recomendable", "Estandar", "Top"))` pero me sale que no tiene el mismo número de filas que el resto del dataframe.

Intenté realizar esto pero ni siquiera sé si es correcto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco mucho si me pudieran ayudar por favor, es el único apartado que me queda de mi trabajo final y si no no puedo continuar con el curso.
Gracias de antemano,

Saludos

Comment: Bienvenida Cristina 97 a Stack Overflow en español, es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: Hola Cristina, algunos "tips", 1) por favor no escribas todo seguido en mayúsculas, imagino ya sabes que es como estar gritando. 2) La idea de lo ejercicios académicos es que tú los resuelvas, flaco favor te haríamos si lo hiciera la comunidad 3) ¿Esto quiere decir que no podemos ayudarte? no claro que no, pero la comunidad pide en estos casos  mostrar un esfuerzo de tu parte en resolverlo, agregando el código de lo que hubieras intentado hasta ahora y las dificultades con las que te encontraste. 4) Usa el buscador de SO, esto que preguntas ya se preguntado varias veces. Saludos.

Comment: Revisa esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/384091/aplicar-una-condicional-a-una-serie-de-rangos-en-r cre que puede ayudarte

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Aplicar una condicional a una serie de rangos en r](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/384091/aplicar-una-condicional-a-una-serie-de-rangos-en-r)